# Beeping hard disk in a multiple hard disk configuration

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

I've been hearing a continuous beeping sound coming from my hard disk. The problem is, I have 2 hard disks and I'm not sure which one it was.

My primary hard disk is WD 250gb and the second one is a brand new Seagate 2tb (I'm still under the 1 week replacement warranty). Either of them started beeping after I reformatted my primary HDD. The beeping continues and I've had a boot failure 3 times. I've unplugged the second HDD and the beeping went away, and the boot was succesful this time. I've added back the second HDD and it's working perfectly.

Which HDD was most likely to have had that beeping sound?
Will my HDD last long after recovering from a stuck spindle?

Comment: Have you managed to figure out which part of the hard drive the beeping is coming from?

Comment: Im guessing it was my primary HDD with the OS cause I had bootdisk failure. but I just cant figure out how the beeping sound was gone after I unplugged the 2nd HDD.

Comment: Don't guess. Open the damn case and LISTEN.

Comment: The beeping sound was gone. Im just trying to figure out if my new secondary HDD made that sound so I can replace it since its still under 1 week replacement warranty. I dont care much if it was my primary HDD since my important files are on my secondary HDD.

Comment: A beeping noise most likely indicates a stuck spindle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hard Drive malfunction : rapid beeping noise and not being recognized by computer](http://superuser.com/questions/757697/hard-drive-malfunction-rapid-beeping-noise-and-not-being-recognized-by-compute)

Answer (score 1):

If the beeping sound went away after you unplugged the 2nd HDD, then maybe the 2nd HDD was beeping...!

As the drive(s) no longer beep, it wouldn't be a bad idea to make sure they still work (If it was completely dead, it wouldn't beep).

To figure out which one was beeping, put a microphone (from you're phone or another computer's headset) next to each one and see which has the louder beep.